# How to rename a bunch of files with a specific pattern

Tags: linux

I want to rename the files in a directory which are named with this pattern:

```
string1-number.html
```

for example:

```
English-5.html
```

what I want to do is to rename the files like this:

```
string2-number.string3
```

for example:

```
Dictionary-5.en
```

How can I do this?
I used this script, but nothing happened:

```
echo "English-5.html" | sed   's%\({English}\).\(\.*\)\(html\)%dictionary\2\en%'
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the mmv tool: http://linux.dsplabs.com.au/mmv-copy-append-link-move-multiple-files-under-linux-shell-bash-by-wildcard-patterns-p5/

With that you can do:

```
mmv *-*.html Dictionary-#2.en
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "English-5.html" | sed 's%English\(-[0-9][0-9]*.\)html%dictionary\1en%'
```

Explanation:

I'm looking for `English`

followed by a dash, one or more numbers, and a dot `-[0-9][0-9]*.` (I surround this part with escaped parenthesis to make it a group (group 1)).

followed by `html`

In the replacement text, I use `\1` to output the contents of group 1, as well as the changed text.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 errors: The `{...}` is not required, and you confused `\.` and `.`

`\.` matches a literal dot, while `.` matches a single character.

```
echo "English-5.html" |
sed 's%\(English\)\(.*\)\.\(html\)%dictionary\2.en%'
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer shows some minor optimizations for `sed` commands already posted and shows how to actually rename the files (in the current folder):

```
 for f in *; do mv "$f" $(echo "$f" |\
 sed 's/^English-\([0-9]\+\)\.html$/dictionary-\1\.en/'); done
```